# running script with ". " and with "source "

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

1. I was wondering if the following two ways of running a bash script
   are equivalent?

   ```
   . ./myScript.sh

   source myScript.sh
   ```
2. Are they both running the content of the script instead of running the script, i.e. not creating a subshell for running the script?

Comment: Hey, that's in the manpage!

Comment: @alex: show me please? `man .`, `man source` or whatever I haven't know yet.

Comment: See `type .` and `help .`

Comment: `man $SHELL`, `/source`

Comment: [. is more portable](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/nonportable) according to others.

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25488/what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-in-bash , except this is on topic =)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. They are equivalent in bash in that they do exactly the same thing.  On the other hand, `source` is 5 characters longer and is not portable to POSIX-only shells or Bourne whereas `.` (dot) is, so I never bother using `source`.
2. That is correct - sourcing a file runs the commands in the current shell and it will affect your current shell environment.  You can still pass arguments to the sourced file and bash will actually look in `$PATH` for the file name just like a normal command if it doesn't contain any slashes.

---

Not related to the original question of `.` vs `source`, but in your example,

```
. ./myScript.sh
```

is not identical to

```
source myScript.sh
```

because while `.` and `source` are functionally identical, `myScript.sh` and `./myScript.sh` are not the same.  Since `./myScript.sh` contains a slash, it's interpreted as a path and the shell just uses `./myScript.sh`.  However, `myScript.sh` does not have a slash so the shell does a `$PATH` search for it first.  This is the [POSIX specified standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) behavior for `.`.  Most shells default to this although they may add extensions (such as searching in the current working directory after the path search) or options to change the behavior of `.`/`source`.

Comment: the behavior when the provided path of the file doesn't contain a `/` is shell-dependent and for `bash` and `zsh` depends on whether the POSIX mode is enabled or not. Also note that in many ksh implementations, `.` behaves differently from `source`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yes, you are right.  I added a note to clarify that it the above description is of the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they are equivalent. There is no functional difference; `.` is just a builtin synonym for `source`.

<sub>(Edit: Apparently this is only true for `bash` and `zsh`. Some lighter shells don't have `source`, only `.` is specified by POSIX so `ksh`, `dash`, `ash`, etc. may not have `source`. See [jw013's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source/17885#17885) for info.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! But `$ alias .` outputs `bash: alias: .: not found
`.

Comment: That is they are both builtins and the alias is builtin too. This is [documented](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html), but I guess 'synonym' is the right term in this case, not 'alias'.