# What is the difference between '.' and 'source' in shells?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, bashrc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [running script with “. ” and with “source ”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source)

I have used both the dot command '.' and 'source' to reload a given rc file (typically to update my environment variables) but I am not sure if they are different and if one is preferred. What is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`.` is the Bourne and POSIX shell command while `source` is the C-Shell command.

Some Bourne-shell derivatives like `bash`, `zsh` and most implementations of `ksh` also have a `source` command which is generally an alias for `.` - however, it may behave slightly differently (e.g. in zsh and ksh).

For bash, `.` and `source` behave the same, but their behaviour is affected by whether they are run in POSIX mode or not¹.

POSIX requires that the `.` command exits the shell process² if it can't open the file for reading and requires that the file be found through a search of the directories in `$PATH` if the provided path doesn't contain a `/`.

`csh`'s `source` interprets the argument as a path, and never looks the file up in `$PATH`.

bash `.` and `source` behave as POSIX requires when in POSIX mode, and as pdksh's `source` when not, that is they don't exit the script if they fail to open the file for reading (same as `command .`) and lookup the file in `$PATH` **and the current directory** if the provided path doesn't contain a `/`.

zsh `.` behaves as POSIX requires, while `source` looks in the current directory *first* and then `$PATH` (even in `csh` emulation) when the argument doesn't contain a `/`. (see [`info zsh .`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e) and [`info zsh source`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-source) for details). If `.` or `source` fail to find/open the file, that only aborts the shell when in POSIX mode (`sh` emulation) though.

AT&T ksh's `source` doesn't exit the shell either but doesn't look for the file in the current directory.

All in all, in Bourne-like shells (though not the Bourne shell that doesn't have a `command` builtin), if you want a consistent behaviour, you could do

```
command . /path/to/the-file-to-source || handle-error
```

And if *the-file-to-source* is meant to be in the current directory, be sure to write:

```
command . ./the-file-to-source || handle-error
```

In `sh` scripts (where `sh` is a POSIX `sh`) you should be able to rely on the POSIX behaviour stated above.

---

<sup>¹ `zsh` and `bash` enable the POSIX mode when called as `sh`. For `bash`, also when it receives `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in its environment (even when called as bash even though there's no POSIX command called `bash`), or when it receives `SHELLOPTS=posix`, or when called with `bash --posix` or `bash -o posix` or after a `set -o posix`. With zsh, you use `emulate sh` to *emulate* `sh`. Emulations alter a whole bunch of options that change the behaviour of zsh. In this case, the option is `POSIX_BUILTINS`.</sup>

<sup>In bash, you can check if in  POSIX mode or not with the (non-POSIX), `[ -o posix ]` command. In zsh, you check the output of `emulate` to see if you're in `sh` emulation, or `[[ -o posixbuiltins ]]` to check whether that particular option is enabled. You can also temporarily enable a given emulation mode with `emulate -L` (to emulate in the current *local* scope only).</sup>

<sup>² for non-interactive shells. For interactive shells, the behaviour varies between shells, some ignore the failure, some will return to the prompt like some syntax errors would. Also, when run in a subshell, that exits the subshell only.</sup>

Comment: Great answer, do you also happen to know, if you use bash or zsh, how do you find out what mode you're in? I mean, save for testing with a file that does not exist.

Comment: I still don't understand why `zsh` uses the current working directory if the path doesn't contain any `/` with `source` but not with `.`. Or maybe that has changed in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 2):

`source` is there for readability and self-documentation, `.` exists because it is quick to type.  The commands are identical.  Perl has long and short versions of many of its control variables for the same reason.

Comment: `source` and `.` behave different in zsh. `source` searches the current directory, `.` doesn't