# Why was `.` chosen to represent the dot command?

Tags: command, history, historical-unix

I am wondering after seeing [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/459087/237982) question why the `.` symbol was chosen to represent the [dot command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot)?

I am not able to find much about it's origin or who created it and am curious as to why a [full stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) was chosen to represent this command.

Comment: Did you try to ask Stephen Bourne?

Comment: @schily: He wasn't available to chat

Comment: He may answer a mail. He cannot answer about what happened to the shell past 1982 but this happened between 1976 and 1979.

Comment: Because it would be silly to call "%" the "dot command".

Comment: Is your question why did they choose to use `.`?

Comment: @slm: Correct, why was `.` used to represent the dot(source) command?  Is it related to `.` being the current directory?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459103/261962

Comment: @Rob: How is it relevant?

Comment: "I am not able to find much about it's origin or who created it and am curious as to why a full stop was chosen to represent this command." - It's the answer.

Comment: @Rob: No it's not.

Comment: Actual "answers" don't go in comments, you said you could not find much; that's a start. I can spend more time on this tomorrow, after my job jar is not so full.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280656/where-does-and-come-from

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest mentioning of the dot command that I can find is in [the manual for Stephen Bourne's `sh` shell in Unix Release 7](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man1/sh.1#L704) (it may be older, but not evidently present as one of the built-in commands in [`sh` in Release 6](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/source/s2/sh.c#L559)).

```
. file  Read and execute commands from file and return.  The search path
        $PATH is used to find the directory containing file.
```

The dot, in quite general terms, seems to have been associated with "here" or "current".  The `.` directory is the *current directory*, and the `.` address in the `adb` debugger from the same release of Unix had a `.` address which was the *current address*.  Likewise, entering a `.` followed by newline in the `ed` editor will re-display the *current line* of the editing buffer (`.` addresses the current line).  The dot also means the *current node* in certain structured query languages for XML, JSON, YAML, etc. (although these are later inventions).

It is therefore, I think, not too far fetched to speculate that the `.` command in the shell also means "here" or "current".  In particular, "run this script in the *current environment*."

The dot is also quite quick and easy to type, and having a short command for doing a common task (whether it be in `ed`, `adb` or in the shell) may have been another reason why another longer name was not used.

---

Note that I don't have a functioning version of `sh` from Release 7 to test things in, and that [I can't find the actual *implementation* of `.`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/cmd/sh/builtin.c) in Bourne's shell from that release in the above-mentioned Git repository, so I can't say for sure that it actually did exactly what it does today.  But it's likely that it did.

Comment: +1. Thanks for this long answer. By the way, is there any difference between dot and source when used to run commands from a file: `. scriptfile` versus `source scriptfile` in `bash`? In other words, are they two names of the same built-in command?

Comment: @sudodus They are equivalent. The `source` command has a different history though, as it's inherited from `csh`.

Answer (score 2):

May it be because `dot` is the name of the symbol `.`.

[1 : a small spot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dot)

Comment: +1. Yes of course, this is the short answer ;-)