# Equivalent to "source" in OpenBSD?

Tags: python, environment-variables, ksh, openbsd, virtualenv

Trying to open a python3 virtual environment I have created with

```
python3 -m venv myVenv
```

by doing

```
source myVenv/bin/activate
```

as I do in Linux, but I get

```
ksh: source: not found
```

which mean it is not in my path/installed. When I try to add it with `pkg_add`, it just tell me it can't find it. Does OpenBSD use something else that allows me to use venv or what should I do?

Comment: `source` is a `bash` command. To switch to `bash` as your login shell, if this would make your life easier, install the `bash` port/package and update your login shell with `chsh`.  `bash` would be installed as `/usr/local/bin/bash` on OpenBSD.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using the Forsyth PD Korn shell, the usual login shell on OpenBSD.  The PD Korn shell does not have a `source` command.  The `source` built-in command is only available in some shells.  The command that you want is the `.` command.

## Further reading

- [What is the difference between '.' and 'source' in shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58514/)

Answer (score 10):

The `source` keyword which is available in `bash` is not part of the Posix standard. Instead you can use

```
. myVenv/bin/activate
```

You could use the same syntax with `.` in `bash` which you are using on your Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can simply launch a new bash shell, and source it there:

```
ksh$ bash
bash$ source myVenv/bin/activate
(myVenv) bash$ python ...
```

As a bonus, this gives you an easy way to deactivate the venv and return to a pristine environment: just `exit` from the bash shell and you'll return to ksh!