# Difference between ways in script execution

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to ask you the differences between the following ways in script execution.

```
.  script.sh      
../script.sh
. ./script.sh
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i) and [Why do we use “./” (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Comment: Did you type them all as intended? The middle one refers to a different file.

Answer (score 5):

```
   script.sh
 ./script.sh
../script.sh
```

All of the above have the shell ask the kernel to execute the given file, which doesn't need to be a shell script (regardless of the name). The first looks for the file in `PATH`, the second in the current directory (`.`), the third in the parent directory.

```
.    script.sh
.  ./script.sh
. ../script.sh
source    script.sh
source  ./script.sh
source ../script.sh
```

Both `.` and `source` ask the shell itself to open and read the given file as shell commands, executed in the *current shell*, almost as if the commands inside were just given on the shell command line. That is, e.g. all variable assignments made in the sourced script are visible in the shell afterwards, which is not the case for regular execution. `source` is non-standard synonym for `.`. The first again looks for the file in `PATH`, the second in the current directory, and the third in the parent directory. Similarly for the other three.

<sub>(Except in Zsh, `source` looks at the current directory first, unlike `.`; and in Bash, if the `shopt` setting `sourcepath` is disabled, neither `.` or `source` search the `PATH`.)</sub>

See:

- [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/170373)
- [What is the difference between '.' and 'source' in shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58514/170373)
- [Why do we use "./" (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4430/170373)
- [Different ways to execute a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/170373), and
- any resource on the filesystem structure and paths.