# Can a bash script add to the context of zsh?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, portability, source-command

I have recently migrated from bash to zsh.

I used to use the following `token_refresh.sh` script to `ssh-add` my private key to the session:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "configuring ssh access.."
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ./my-key
```

However, I can't run this directly from zsh in the dir /ssh:

```
$ ls
my-key  my-key.pub  token_refresh.sh
$ . token_refresh.sh
.: no such file or directory: token_refresh.sh
```

I can run bash scripts using

```
bash token_refresh.sh
```

However, doesn't that start a bash session, `ssh-add` the key to the bash session, then exits.

How can I portably run this script in bash and zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mention the path when you source the file:

```
. ./token_refesh.sh
```

This is needed in shells where the dot command does not look in the current directory by default.

Since the script is a "dot-script" (meant to be sourced), you can remove the `#!`-line from it.  That line has no effect whatsoever and will always be interpreted as a comment.

See also:

- [What is the difference between '.' and 'source' in shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58514/what-is-the-difference-between-and-source-in-shells)

Comment: Is it not good practice to always include a shebang for shell scripts?

Comment: @StuperUser It's not a shell script.  It is a set of commands that the _current_ shell will execute.  A shell script is run in a shell separate from (a child process of) the current shell.  This sort of "script" is therefore sometimes called "dot script".  The commands will be executed by the current shell regardless of what the comment on the first line says.