# ZSH: What's the difference between `.` and `source`?

Tags: shell, zsh

I used to think that the built-ins `.` and `source` are equivalent. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source) agrees with me when it comes to `bash`. However I encountered the following using `zsh`:

```
desktop➜  ~/pst  . env
/usr/bin/env:1: no such file or directory:  ^@^A^@^@^@X^Z@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\M-8q^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@
/usr/bin/env:2: parse error near `)'
desktop➜  ~/pst  source env
desktop➜  ~/pst  file env
env: ASCII text
```

`source` did what I expected, but what's `.` trying to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`man zshall` has the answer:

> ```
>    source file [ arg ... ]
>           Same as `.', except that the current directory is always searched and is always searched first, before directories in $path.
> ```

Example:

```
desktop➜  ~/pst  source /bin/env
/bin/env:1: no such file or directory: ^@^A^@^@^@X^Z@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\M-8q^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@
/bin/env:2: parse error near `)'
desktop➜  ~/pst  . env
/usr/bin/env:1: no such file or directory: ^@^A^@^@^@X^Z@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@\M-8q^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@
/usr/bin/env:2: parse error near `)'
```