# Is it OK to use "." to run files instead of source - in .bashrc in Ubuntu and OS X?

Tags: osx, bashrc, posix

OK, so `source` runs the script in the current shell and `.` separately, as detailed in [running script with ". " and with "source "](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/running-script-with-and-with-source) for example, but, specifically, in my **`.bashrc`** file, I have:

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && source ~/.bash_aliases
[ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ] && source ~/.git-completion.bash
[ -s ~/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ] && source ~/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```

Can I replace this with:

```
[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ] && . ~/.bash_aliases
[ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ] && . ~/.git-completion.bash
[ -s ~/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh ] && . ~/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
```

Will that work on OS X - is that the "POSIX" issue?

I tried it and the above still seem to work on Ubuntu (so they actually work with both `source` and `.`, that is, they give me the desired functionality in the shell). Should I choose one over the other, or am I missing something?

FWIW, on OS X, I source my `.bashrc` from my `.bash_profile`.

Comment: If it is 'sh' based shells I'd be using '.' for global compatibility and if you are using 'csh' based shells I'd be using source.

Comment: Where in the linked post are you seeing that "`source` runs the script in the current shell and `.` separately"? They both run it in the current shell; otherwise there'd be no point

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [POSIX's definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) of `.dot`:

> The shell shall execute commands from the file in the current
>   environment.
>
> If file does not contain a `/<slash>`, the shell shall use the search
>   path specified by `$PATH` to find the directory containing file. Unlike
>   normal command search, however, the file searched for by the `.dot`
>   utility need *not* be executable. If no readable file is found, a
>   non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a
>   diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be
>   considered a syntax error.

Considering the above, you might as well just replace your `[ -f ./file ] && source ./file` with `. ./file` altogether. If the file is not there the worst that will happen is you'll get a notice at login - which is probably information you'd want to have, I think.

Of course if you'd rather keep the test you could do:

```
test -f ./file && . $_
```

Comment: Oh, people knowing `$_`, I like that. :)

Comment: @AndreasWiese - everyone should - it's one of only some 7 special parameters defined by POSIX.

Comment: +1 I ended up using the `test -f /.file && . $_` approach shown here

Comment: @mikeserv No, `$_` is not standardized by POSIX. The [8 special parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) are `$@`, `$*`, `$#`, `$$`, `$!`, `$?`, `$-` and `$0`. `$_` is [explicitly omitted](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_05_03). Your incorrect comment sparked a [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129272/where-is-defined-by-posix).

Answer (score 20):

In `bash`, `.` and `source` are synonyms. Looking into `bash` source code, file `builtin/source.def`, you can see `.` and `source` use the same internal function `source_builtin`:

```
$BUILTIN source
$FUNCTION source_builtin
$SHORT_DOC source filename [arguments]
Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
when FILENAME is executed.

Exit Status:
Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
FILENAME cannot be read.
$END

$BUILTIN .
$DOCNAME dot
$FUNCTION source_builtin
$SHORT_DOC . filename [arguments]
Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
```

But `source` is not POSIX compatible, so if your script is called with POSIX `/bin/sh`, you should use `.` instead of `source`. Since POSIX doesn't restrict the shell, all your above script will work.

Personally, I always use `.` instead of `source`. (A lot of scripts that I wrote run under `cron`).

Comment: All things being equal, use "source" instead of "." for one reason:  try to search/grep for "." expressions in a large script.  It's a nightmare.

Comment: Although this answer explains why using `.` is usually "better" than using `source`, as @abonet says, `source` is a lot easier to search for. Since periods are punctuation in many languages, it's easy for the eye to just skip over them. That's why I prefer to use `source`.