# Where is $_ defined by POSIX?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, posix

In the [comments to the accepted answer to this Unix & Linux StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128830/is-it-ok-to-use-to-run-files-instead-of-source-in-bashrc-in-ubuntu-and-os#comment206503_128834), it is stated that `$_` is "one of only some 7 special parameters defined by POSIX".  I can't find that definition although I can find eight other [special parameters defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) and I've seen `$_` defined in the [ksh](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Parameter%20Expansion) and [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) man pages.  Can someone point me to the definition in POSIX?

Comment: Neither the question you link to nor its answers claim that `$_` is POSIX.

Comment: @terdon It's a [comment by mikeserv](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128830/is-it-ok-to-use-to-run-files-instead-of-source-in-bashrc-in-ubuntu-and-os#comment206503_128834). He's wrong.

Comment: @terdon I've updated my question to clarify where that statement is in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only reference I can find to the special parameter `$_` in POSIX is in the rationale section on [Shell Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_05_03). This excerpt implies that it was used by a variety of shells, but not in a standard way by all and was omitted intentionally:

> _
>
> (Underscore.) While underscore is historical practice, its overloaded usage in the
>   KornShell is confusing, and it has been omitted from the Shell and Utilities volume
>   of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001.

So it may be used by most or all POSIX-conforming shells, but it is decidedly not defined by POSIX.

Comment: At least Debian dash, Busybox dash and mksh only set `$_` when they are interactive.