# setting bash shell varible to pwd

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to set a shell variable to $PWD - the path from were the script is executed. This is what I have, setenv.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export WORK_AREA=$PWD      #also tried "$PWD", $(pwd), `pwd`
```

But when I run from the shell

```
> ./setenv.sh
> echo $WORK_AREA
```

WORK_AREA has no value

Comment: Try `. ./setenv.sh`

Comment: Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214079/differentiating-between-running-and-being-sourced-in-a-bash-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export` works "downwards" not "upwards". When you export a value in the script that's a child of the shell, it will not export it to the shell that's its parent. It will only change the environment for its own children.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source the script if you want it to affect your current shell environment, e.g.:

```bsh
source setenv.sh
```

Or, using the dot-notation:

```bsh
. setenv.sh
```

When you execute a script it runs in a subshell, as if you had run it using the `bash` command. Changes in the subshell environment do not affect the parent environment. Note that we're only talking about environment variables here. If you modify a file in a subshell then that change will definitely carry over to the parent shell.

See the related SuperUser post:

- [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it)