# . /path/to/a/shell-script-file ? (within a shell script)

Tags: bash, shell

What does `. /path/to/a/shell-script-file`
do exactly? I mean obviously it executes that shell script but why put that `.` followed by a space before the path/name of the script file?

Comment: I missed the space after the period, so my answer was totally inaccurate and I deleted it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different ways to execute a shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/80216)  Related: [running a script with “.” and with “source”](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17815/80216).

Answer (score 10):

`.` or `source` tells the shell to execute the script itself, instead of forking a sub-shell to run it in.

This allows the script to modify the environment of the shell.

For example, if you have a script that sets certain environment variables or defines aliases then running it without `.` will define those things in a sub-shell, and they will disappear when the sub-shell terminates.  Running it with `.` will define them in the current shell.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file of custom environment settings (aliases, additions to $PATH, etc). Call the file `custom_env`.

Usually this stuff will go in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`. But sometimes you might want it in separate file, then you can apply it to your session as needed, e.g.

```
. ./custom_env
```